# neovim change keybind only for specific buffer type/plugin

Tags: neovim

In neovim, I have my leader mapped to `space`.

I also use nvim-tree.

What I want: when nvim-tree is open and that is the active buffer (cursor is there), map leader to something else so I can use `space` to expand folders in the tree. This feels most natural to me.

Is there a way to do this? Seems like it'd be useful broadly to have environment dependent keymaps

Comment: You can always use `<localleader>` with `<buffer>`-specific mappings.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try

Comment: I think I got it working

Comment: please post an answer if you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

In require("nvim-tree").setup(), add the space key (or any key) as an 'edit' keymap and it'll automatically override other mappings to that key when in the tree context. I thought I'd have to manually configure this but it just works out of the box:

```
  view = {
    ...
    mappings = {
      ...
      list = {
        { key = {" ", "<other edit keys>"}, cb = tree_cb("edit") },
```